# Read hex file in java and traduce it into ascii

Tags: java, hex, ascii

Good Morning i have a serius problem. 
I need to read a file in hex ​​and translate it into ascii. 
I also need to write the ascii on another file.
I tried so:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("fileAscii");
    int read;
    String hex = "";
    int count = 0;
    String valueRead="";
    PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter("fileOutput");

    while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
        count++;
        valueRead= Integer.toHexString(read);
        if(valueRead.length()==1){
            hex=hex+"0";
        }
        hex = hex + valueRead;
        if (is16Multipler(count)) {

            System.out.println(hex);
            String sb = "";
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {

                //grab the hex in pairs
                String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
                //convert hex to decimal
                int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
                //convert the decimal to character
                sb=sb+(char) decimal;


            }
            if(!sb.equals("00000000000000000000000000000000"))
            {
               writer.println(sb.toString());
            }


               hex = "";
        }
    }
}


public static boolean is16Multipler(int number) {
    if (number % 16 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the problem is that I read the wrong values ​​for example read 83  bat the original file contains 84

Comment: The program seems to convert bytes it reads to hex and not the other way round.

Comment: It read this:                                  6f726b73686f702e636f6d002e466c0b
24d77901080009000000000014031f06
2e31616e64312e6974002e487b937d25                                       that is hex format

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex file'. There is binary and there is text. This is binary. What your present code does is convert binary to hex and then hex to ASCII, not always accurately. The point escapes me.

Comment: There are of course real "hex" files - for example, those which contain binary data to be programmed to a ROM chip (or today, micro-controller FLASH), represented in human readable (and 7-bit transmittable) ASCII-encoded hex typically line by line with prefixing record type and address and trailing checksum.  But this question concerns a misunderstanding, rather than such a real case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will read your input fileof HEx and write into a file as ASCII characters

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileAscii")); // to read a single line from the file
        int read;
        String src= new String();       // to store the string obtained from buffered reader
        PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter("fileOutput");
        src=br.readLine();              // read an input line from the file

        while(src!=null){
            src=src.replace(" ", "");   // Trim out the spaces
            for(int i=0;i<src.length();i+=2){
                read=Integer.parseInt(src.substring(i,i+2), 16);    // convert the String to hex integer 
                writer.print((char)read);                           // convert hex to char and write into file
            }
            src=br.readLine();
        }
        writer.flush();
    }
```

Comment: I find this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "��"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:35)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Solved: the problem is notepad++ . If I open the output file whit notepad++ the result file is more different from real file. But if I open the output file whit the classic notepad the result file is the real file. 

Thanks and sorry if I have wasted your time. :D

Comment: Please don't mention. It was worth the effort helping you.